# Java repaint() not working on call

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint

I wonder why the repiant() method is not working as intended any more ... Ex :

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{

private ArrayList<Node> nodes;
private ArrayList<Edge> edges;
private boolean AddNode;
private int no_Of_Nodes;
private int width = 30, height = 30;


public static void main(String[] args){
    Main M = new Main();
    M.Start();
}

public void Start() {
    nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("SFG");
    JPanel main_Panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();//Buttons Containser
    JPanel draw = new JPanel();
    ArrayList<JButton> bs = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Add Node");
    b1.addActionListener(new Add_Node());
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Add Edge");
    b2.addActionListener(new Add_Edge());
    JButton b3 = new JButton("Add Arc");
    b3.addActionListener(new Add_Arc());
    JButton b4 = new JButton("Clear all");
    b4.addActionListener(new Clear());
    JButton b5 = new JButton("Solve");
    b5.addActionListener(new Solve());
    Bs.add(b1);
    Bs.add(b2);
    Bs.add(b3);
    Bs.add(b4);
    Bs.add(b5);
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.size(); i++) {
        Buttons.add(bs.get(i));
    }
    Buttons.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    main_Panel.add(Buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    draw.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    draw.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    draw.addMouseListener(this);
    main_Panel.add(Draw);
    main_Panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    f.add(main_Panel);
    f.setSize(1024, 600);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

And these are methods

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    this.repaint();
}

public class Add_Node implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Add Node");
        addNode = true;
    }

}
```

Now here when I add node and call repaint nothing appears in the paint area :

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(addNode){
        addNode(arg0);
        addNode = !addNode;
    }
    System.out.println(nodes.size());
    this.repaint();
}

private void addNode(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int x = arg0.getX();
    int y = arg0.getY();
    Node n = new Node(No_Of_Nodes++);
    n.setX_Pos(X);
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    n.setX_Pos(Y);
    nodes.add(n);
}
```

And that's my paint() method which is not working anymore

```
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponents(g);
            FontMetrics f = g.getFontMetrics();
            int nodeHeight = Math.max(height, f.getHeight());
            System.out.println("In repaint");
        for (Node n : nodes) {
                System.out.println(n.getX_Pos() + " " + n.getY_Pos());
                int nodeWidth = Math.max(width, f.stringWidth(Integer.toString(n.getNode_ID()))+width/2);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillOval(n.getX_Pos()-nodeWidth/2, n.getY_Pos()-nodeHeight/2, nodeWidth, nodeHeight);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawOval(n.getY_Pos()-nodeWidth/2, n.getY_Pos()-nodeHeight/2, nodeWidth, nodeHeight);
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(n.getNode_ID()) , n.getX_Pos()-f.stringWidth(Integer.toString(n.getNode_ID()))/2, n.getY_Pos()+f.getHeight()/2);
            }
         }
```

TIA and sorry for long question :)

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent` not `paint`. Overriding `paint` and not at least calling `super.paint(g)` is asking for problems.

Comment: This; `paint`, followed by this; `super.paintComponents(g);`  is VERY worrying.  Don't override `paint` and especially DON'T circumvent the painting process and then wonder why it doesn't work anymore.  Move your custom painting to the `JPanel`'s `paintComponent` method and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting (note the lack of a `s` at the end of the method names there).

Comment: See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Your posted code is too hard to read since the forum highlights your variables as classes. Fix your code before posting on the forum.

Comment: @camickr Ok thanks for note, will take point into consideration next time

Comment: Please don't add meta information to your posts, like adding `[solved]` to the title. Just marking an answer as accepted, as you've done here already, is enough to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `Start` method, you never actually add `Main` to the `JFrame`.  Based on the out of context snippets of code you've provided, I'm left to "assume" that you are overriding `paint` of the `Main` class, this means, `paint` will NEVER be called as it's not actually attached to a displayable component
2. `Start` shouldn't be creating a `JFrame`.  You should create an instance of `Main` and then add it to an instance of a `JFrame`, the two should be separate.  The for `Main` should be created and added to `Main` itself
3. You shouldn't override `paint` (as a general rule), but you should defiantly NOT circumvent the painting process by calling one of the other `paint` methods, like `paintComponents`.  Instead (again "assuming" you're overriding `paint` in `Main`), you should override the `paintComponent` method and call `super.paintComponent` BEFORE you do any custom painting

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Also, you might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others